# Changing CSS filter values via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a very basic image editor but I can't get the range input sliders (#fx-slider) to affect the actual css filter values. This is the code:

```js
function ChangeFilter() {

  var ifx = document.getElementById("canvasFrame");
  var br = document.getElementById("br");
  var ct = document.getElementById("ct");
  var st = document.getElementById("saturate");

ifx.style.WebkitFilter = "brightness(" + br.value * 10 + "%)");
ifx.style.filter = "brightness(" + br.value * 10 + "%)");

ifx.style.WebkitFilter = "contrast(" + ct.value * 10 + "%)");
ifx.style.filter = "contrast(" + ct.value * 10 + "%)");

ifx.style.WebkitFilter = "saturate(" + st.value * 10 + "%)");
ifx.style.filter = "saturate(" + st.value * 10 + "%)");
}
```

```css
#canvasFrame {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  filter: brightness(100%) contrast(100%) saturate(100%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%) contrast(100%) saturate(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="canvasFrame">
  <img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
<div class="fx-slider">
  <label for="br">Brightness</label>
  <input id="br" name="br" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100" onchange="ChangeFilter()">
</div>
<div class="fx-slider">
  <label for="ct">Contrast</label>
  <input id="ct" name="ct" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100" onchange="ChangeFilter()">
</div>
<div class="fx-slider">
  <label for="st">Saturation</label>
  <input id="st" name="ct" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100" onchange="ChangeFilter()">
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks. :)

Comment: You have a few basic typo errors. The elements have `class` but you are using `getElementById`. There is an extra `)` after the quotes in the lines that set the style.

Comment: also it's `webkitFilter` not `WebkitFilter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an id to your canvas container, and you using the wrong id for your saturation control.  Also, you should be concatenating the 3 controls, otherwise you are only going to set the saturation level.

```
function ChangeFilter() {
  var ifx = document.getElementById("canvasFrame");  //need to update this id in you html
  var br = document.getElementById("br");
  var ct = document.getElementById("ct");
  var st = document.getElementById("st");  //this id was wrong in your code

  //set all 3 filter values at once.
  ifx.style.webkitFilter = "brightness(" + br.value * 10 + "%) contrast(" + ct.value * 10 + "%) saturate(" + st.value * 10 + "%)";
  ifx.style.filter = "brightness(" + br.value * 10 + "%) contrast(" + ct.value * 10 + "%) saturate(" + st.value * 10 + "%)";
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/nobrien/pen/BKmevp

Comment: Oh, and I am guessing that you don't really want to be multiplying your filter by 10, so that your percentages go from 1000 to 2000%, but I left it since it was what you doing before.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much. :) I accidentally left the filter value multipliers in there when creating the simplified code that I posted here. Thanks again. Problem solved.